# unexpected poor performance of GMM from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to model some simulated data using the DPGMM classifier from scikitlearn, but I'm getting poor performance. Here is the example I'm using:

```
from sklearn import mixture
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
clf = mixture.DPGMM(n_components=5, init_params='wc')
s = 0.1
a = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=s, size=(1000,))
b = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=s, size=(1000,))
c = np.random.normal(loc=3, scale=s, size=(1000,))
d = np.random.normal(loc=4, scale=s, size=(1000,))
e = np.random.normal(loc=7, scale=s*2, size=(5000,))
noise = np.random.random(500)*8 
data = np.hstack([a,b,c,d,e,noise]).reshape((-1,1))
clf.means_ = np.array([1,2,3,4,7]).reshape((-1,1))
clf.fit(data)
labels = clf.predict(data)
plt.scatter(data.T, np.random.random(len(data)), c=labels, lw=0, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

I would think that this would be exactly the kind of problem that gaussian mixture models would work for. I've tried playing around with alpha, using gmm instead of dpgmm, changing the number of starting components, etc. I can't seem to get a reliable and accurate classification. Is there something I'm just missing? Is there another model that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't iterate long enough for it to *converge*.

Check the value of

```
clf.converged_
```

and try increasing `n_iter` to `1000`.

Note that, however, the `DPGMM` still fails miserably IMHO on this data set, decreasing the number of clusters to just 2 eventually.